# SWF file as a HTML link

Tags: flash, hyperlink

I have swf file, im using code below to display it on my website:

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" width="160" height="264">
<param name="movie" value="http://www.example.com/baner.swf" />
<param name="quality" value="high" />
<param name="wmode" value="transparent">
<embed src="http://www.example.com/baner.swf" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="160" height="264" wmode="transparent" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />
</object>
```

How can I convert this swf file into link? Im trying to achieve it with flashVars so I've added something like that:

```
<param name=FlashVars value="targetURL="http://example.com/">
```

But what's next? Can I make a link from this .swf file without having .fla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot use the FlashVars method without being able to edit the FLA file. My only suggestion would be to absolutely position a transparent element over the top of the SWF, and have this element as a link.

Comment: I've made a png and placed it with <img> in the same <div> with <object>. How can I put png on top of swf? z-index seems to not work
@edit Link works, but mouse cursor doesn't appear. How can i manage that?

Comment: Use CSS - `position:absolute` on the `img` tag, and position it over the SWF with a combination of `top` and `left`. For example: `<img src="image.png" style="position:absolute; top:100" />`

Answer (score 1):

You can't make swf a link without source (fla).

But you can put html href over it and make that a link (positionet absolute).

Comment: I've tried to put my whole <object> inside <a href> but without success.

Comment: No no, u have to put swf normaly on page, and than over put href link and set desired target. Position it absolute and set proper offset (top, bottom, left, right)

Answer (score 0):

You should be using [swfobject](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/)

I think the answer if *I remember right* is that you call the file `test.swf?thing=1&stuff=hello`
`thing` and `stuff` are now available in your swf as `_root.thing` and `_root.test`